# show detail user using codeigniter (move from php to Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can make this code work only using php native but I want to know exactly what it's gonna be if I literally using Codeigniter like there is Controller, Model and View isn't it?  Can you have look and help me move the code to Codeigniter

So this code is about showing all the employee name and next to it there is detail button that would show the detail information about the employee itself

**index.php**

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing_ci");  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  

      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center"> </h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
                               <th width="30%">View</th>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                          ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_dawta" /></td>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('.view_dawta').click(function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"post",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                     $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

**select.php**

```
<?php  
 if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing_ci");  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee WHERE id = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">';  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <br>  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>Name</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>address</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["address"].'</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>gender</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["gender"].'</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>designation</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["designation"].' Year</td>  


                </tr>  
                ';  
      }  
      $output .= "</table></div>";  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Check the documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/index.html). At first you need to install and configure `CI`. And after the installing you will find the exapmles of `Controller`, `Model` and `View` in the project. They will help you to understand how they connected and how they works.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE** this code has not been fully tested and is a *basic* example of how to do what you want.

This assumes that you are using a table called "users" with columns called "id" and "name".

You will need to set up your database connection in /application/config/database.php.

**Model:**

*/application/models/Users_model.php*

This is where ALL of your database queries take place:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // get a list of all users
    public function get_all_users() {

        return $this->db->query("
            SELECT id, name
            FROM users;
        ")->result();
    }

    // get the details for one specific user
    public function get_user(int $id) {

        return $this->db->query("
            SELECT *
            FROM users
            WHERE id = ?;
        ", $id)->result();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

*/application/controllers/Users.php*

This is where all of your requests start. Go to '*domain.com*/users' to access it (or 'localhost/myapp/users' depending on your setup).

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    public function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Users_model');
    }

    // show a list of all users
    public function index() {

        // do this by loading a "view" that formats the data we gather here.
        $this->load->view('display_users_view', [
            'users' => $this->Users_model->get_all_users(),
            'title' => 'Title for your HTML could go here.'
        ]);
    }

    // return the details for one user
    // if $id is not specified, then look for it in a POST variable
    public function get_user($id = null) {

        // get the employee_id from the ajax request
        // this means if $id is set (not null) then make $employee_id = $id. Otherwise, make $employee_id = posted input
        $employee_id = ($id) ? $id : (int) $this->input->post('employee_id');

        $user = $this->Users_model->get_user($employee_id);

        // if the user made an ajax request, send json encoded data
        if (! $this->input->is_ajax_request())
            echo json_encode($user);
        else
            return $user;
    }
}
```

**View:**

*/application/views/display_users_view.php*

I didn't clean up your HTML very much, but I did add scripts to load jquery and a modal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title><?= $title; ?></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <br><br>  
        <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
            <h3 align="center"> </h3>  
            <br>  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                <table class="table table-bordered">  
                    <tr>  
                        <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
                        <th width="30%">View</th>  
                    </tr>  
                    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>  
                    <tr>  
                        <td><?= $user->name; ?></td>  
                        <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?= $user->id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_dawta"></td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <?php endforeach; ?>  
                </table>  
            </div>  
        </div>  

        <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
            <div class="modal-dialog">  
                <div class="modal-content">  
                    <div class="modal-header">  
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                    </div>  
                    <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                    </div>  
                    <div class="modal-footer">  
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>  

        <script>  
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('.view_dawta').click(function(){  
                var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
                $.ajax({  
                    url:"/users/get_user",
                    method:"post",
                    data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                    success:function(data){  
                        $('#employee_detail').html(data);
                        $('#dataModal').modal("show");
                    }  
                });  
            });  
        });  
        </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Keep in mind that this is not checking if the person is allowed to have access to this information. If you want to do that, add something like this to your `__construct()` in the controller:

```
        // if the user isn't logged in, get them out of here
        if ($this->session->userdata('access_level') < 10) {
            $this->output->set_status_header(403);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: In response to your deleted comment: Then change the function signature in the model to `    public function get_user(string $id) {` but you will want to do some data sanitization on it to make sure someone isn't trying to do a SQL injection through your AJAX call.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer it's really help me up throught this framework, but I got another simple question ,how to change in the controller get_users() "when I want to pass variable data from user_mode->get_user($id));     instead of echo json_encode like you did ?.Thanks before

Comment: See my updated `get_user` method for the controller. If any of that doesn't make sense to you, let me know and I will explain it.

Comment: hey man I still curious how to show the user detail data in html like we show all the user in the first place  using foreach()

Comment: Add any additional arguments to the $this->load->view() function in the controller. See how it is using an array to assign a value to the "users" variable? Just add another element to that array. I'll update the example in a moment.

Comment: There. I added an extra variable for "title" which shows up in the view file for the HTML title tag.

Comment: ok , and how can I add this `$user = $this->Users_model->get_user($employee_id);` to show up in the view so we can use foreach loop like we using foreach loop for display all user,

Comment: If there's only one user, you don't need to use `foreach`. `Foreach` is only for arrays. To show it in the view, just do `<?= $user->name; ?>` or `<?= $user->id; ?>` or whatever.